# Unable to copy to SnowFlake from Azure Data Factory Getting Error: SQL error: Object 'FNDMTL_DEV.DBO."Obligations"' does not exist or not authorized.,

Tags: azure-data-factory

When attempting to Copy data to SnowFlake Database with ADF I get the following error:

[image]

The sink and Link Service (connection is parameterized), see below.

[image]

[image]

With the above configuration I get the error:

```
ErrorCode=UserErrorOdbcOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=ERROR [42S02] SQL compilation error:
Object 'FNDMTL_DEV.DBO."Obligations"' does not exist or not authorized.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Runtime.GenericOdbcConnectors,''Type=System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException,Message=ERROR [42S02] SQL compilation error:
Object 'FNDMTL_DEV.DBO."Obligations"' does not exist or not authorized.,Source=SnowflakeODBC_sb64.dll,'
```

However, if I were to hardcode the table as follows, the copying of data to SnowFlake would be successful
[image]

I'm not sure why I get the error when I parameterize the connection.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this [Document](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/faq-when-i-retrieve-database-schema-table-or-column-names-why-does-snowflake-display-them-in-uppercase)

> **Snowflake stores the object names in uppercase, unless you quote, ("") the names when you create the objects.**

As you see when you Hard code all the table name and schema name in Capital letters.

So, when you are parameterizing snowflake dataset you need to pass the names in Capital letters.

[image]

Pipeline getting Succeed:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Pratik, this was exactly the problem, and your answer was the solution. Thank you